# Merge on single level of MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to merge on a single level of a MultiIndex without resetting the index?

I have a "static" table of time-invariant values, indexed by an ObjectID, and I have a "dynamic" table of time-varying fields, indexed by ObjectID+Date. I'd like to join these tables together.

Right now, the best I can think of is:

```
dynamic.reset_index().merge(static, left_on=['ObjectID'], right_index=True)
```

However, the dynamic table is very big, and I don't want to have to muck around with its index in order to combine the values.

Comment: What if you created an additional column with the level of the MultiIndex you want to join on and then merged/joined on that on that? Might not be totally efficient, but at least you maintain the index.

Comment: Yes, that would work. It'd cost some memory, and it wouldn't help speed. At that point, though, I think I might as well drop the index entirely, if it's not going to help speed up merges.

Comment: corresponding github issue https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3662

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, since pandas 0.14.0, it is now possible to merge a singly-indexed DataFrame with a level of a multi-indexed DataFrame using `.join`.

```
df1.join(df2, how='inner') # how='outer' keeps all records from both data frames
```

[The 0.14 pandas docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/merging.html#merging-join-on-mi) describes this as equivalent but more memory efficient and faster than:

```
merge(df1.reset_index(),
      df2.reset_index(),
      on=['index1'],
      how='inner'
     ).set_index(['index1','index2'])
```

The docs also mention that `.join` can not be used to merge two multiindexed DataFrames on a single level and from the GitHub tracker discussion for the previous issue, it seems like this might not of priority to implement:

> so I merged in the single join, see #6363; along with some docs on
> how to do a multi-multi join. That's fairly complicated to actually
> implement. and IMHO not worth the effort as it really doesn't change
> the memory usage/speed that much at all.

However, there is a GitHub conversation regarding this, where there has been some recent development https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6360. It is also possible achieve this by resetting the indices as mentioned earlier and described in the docs as well.

---

## Update for pandas >= 0.24.0

It is now possible to merge multiindexed data frames with each other. As per [the release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#joining-with-two-multi-indexes):

```
index_left = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('K0', 'X0'), ('K0', 'X1'),
                                        ('K1', 'X2')],
                                        names=['key', 'X'])

left = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']}, index=index_left)

index_right = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('K0', 'Y0'), ('K1', 'Y1'),
                                        ('K2', 'Y2'), ('K2', 'Y3')],
                                        names=['key', 'Y'])

right = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                      'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']}, index=index_right)

left.join(right)
```

Out:

```
            A   B   C   D
key X  Y                 
K0  X0 Y0  A0  B0  C0  D0
    X1 Y0  A1  B1  C0  D0
K1  X2 Y1  A2  B2  C1  D1

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: For your first example, how do you select the level of the MultiIndex to use for the join?

Comment: nvm, the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-a-single-index-to-a-multi-index) say that it joins based upon the index level having the same name as the single-level index.

Comment: And joins are extremely fast in pandas

Comment: @HenryHenrinson If you want use the union of the keys from the data frames (i.e. keep all records from both frames and introduce `NaN` as needed to fill the resulting table), use `how=outer`. Since `merge` was used as an example in the question, I used `how=inner`, which is the default behavior for `merge`. You can read more about the different joins available via the `how` parameter in [the pandas documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/merging.html#joining-on-index) and by typing `?pd.DataFrame.join` in your Python console. I added a short note as a comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I get around this by reindexing the dataframe merging to have the full multiindex so that a left join is possible.

```
# Create the left data frame
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['a','b'],['c','d']],labels=[[0,0,1,1],[0,1,0,1]], names=['lvl1','lvl2'])
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4],index=idx,columns=['data'])

#Create the factor to join to the data 'left data frame'
newFactor = pd.DataFrame(['fact:'+str(x) for x in df.index.levels[0]], index=df.index.levels[0], columns=['newFactor'])
```

Do the join on the subindex by reindexing the newFactor dataframe to contain the index of the left data frame

```
df.join(newFactor.reindex(df.index,level=0))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use mapping for a single column:

```
df1['newcol'] = df1.index.get_level_values(-1).map(lambda x: df2.newcol[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
gData.columns = gData.columns.droplevel(0)

grpData = gData.reset_index()
grpData

pd.merge(grpData,cusData,how='inner')
```

Here gData is multi index dataframe with two levels and cusData is a single index dataframe.