# Merge MultiIndex dataframes on one level

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to join two multiindex dataframes on the first level. I have tried with some other solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650945/merge-on-single-level-of-multiindex) but didn't quite work for me. I'm expecting in a way an outer join, but I would also like the values in the  matching indices to be replaced by the ones in `df2`. Otherwise some useful tips on how to easily perform an `outer` merge on the first level would also be appreciated.

**Set up:**

```
dates1 = pd.to_datetime(['1/11/2016','5/11/2016','9/11/2016'])
dates2 = pd.to_datetime(['1/11/2016','4/11/2016','8/11/2016','9/11/2016'])
v1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[112,112,112], dates1])
v2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[113,113,113, 113], dates2])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'active1':[3,3,4],'active2':[5,1,10]}, index = v1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'active1':[1,22,12,5],'active2':[5,1,12,13]}, index = v2)

print(df1)
                  active1  active2
112 2016-01-11        3        5
    2016-05-11        3        1
    2016-09-11        4       10

print(df2)
                   active1  active2
113 2016-01-11        1        5
    2016-04-11       22        1
    2016-08-11       12       12
    2016-09-11        5       13
```

**Expected output**:

```
                  active1  active2
112 2016-01-11        1        5
    2016-04-11       22        1
    2016-05-11        3        1
    2016-08-11       12       12
    2016-09-11        5       13
```

Comment: How should the join work when there's more than one unique 0th level value in each frame? Or is that never the case?

Comment: The idea would be to only use the first level for the outer join, and keep the level 0 index from `df1`

Comment: Yes I get that, but it's totally unclear what you expect if `df1` has another row `117 2016-09-14 5 5` and `df2` has another row `115 2016-01-11 17 14`. Should the output have 2 levels? Should 2016-01-11 be repeated twice in each one?

Comment: I'm only going to be working with one unique level 0 index for both cases. The complete dfs have more, But this is after some filtering steps which only select one level 0 index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the level 0 value is unique, ignore it, use `.combine_first` to merge the `DataFrames` on the other index giving priority to values in `df2` when matched, and then add the index back in the end from `df1`

```
(df2.reset_index(0, drop=True)
    .combine_first(df1.reset_index(0, drop=True))
    .assign(l0 = df1.index[0][0])
    .set_index('l0', append=True)
    .swaplevel(0,1)
    .rename_axis([None, None], 0))
```

#### Output

```
                active1  active2
112 2016-01-11      1.0      5.0
    2016-04-11     22.0      1.0
    2016-05-11      3.0      1.0
    2016-08-11     12.0     12.0
    2016-09-11      5.0     13.0
```

---

If you have `null` values in your `DataFrames` and you don't want `nulls` in `df2` to be updated with `df1` then you can first replace them with dummy values (like `999999`) and replace back with `NaN` after the combine.

Comment: Thanks @alollz :) Yes `combine_first`
 works quite nicely for this, but was having trouble on joining both dataframes ignoring the first index. Nice solution!

Comment: @yatu. The difficulty is that your indices do not have names, so you are unable to reference a single level. If you give then names: `df1.index.names = ['level_0', 'level_1']` and 
`df2.index.names = ['level_0', 'level_1']` then you can merge on just the first level with: `df1.merge(df2, on='level_1', how='outer')`. But now you'll need to implement logic to combine the columns, which is what combine first does essentially does for you.

Comment: Yes true, it is not the nicest setting to work with. Thanks a lot for your solution and thoughts!